# Adding contraints on functions in Z3

Tags: c++, z3

I am trying to get Z3 to find interpretations for some functions on integers. I ran into a queer little problem. I've written a small piece of code that illustrates it:

```
#include "z3++.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace z3;
main()
{
    context c;
    sort I=c.int_sort();
    func_decl trial1=function("trial1",I,I);
    func_decl trial2=function("trial2",I,I,I);
    solver s(c);
    expr temp=trial1(1)==2;
    cout<<temp<<endl;
    s.add(temp);
    //temp=trial2(1,2)==3;
    temp=trial2(c.int_val(1),c.int_val(2))==3;
    cout<<temp<<endl;
    s.add(temp);

}
```

In this code, the line that is commented out causes an error. But the alternative that I have written underneath works just fine. The reason for my confusion is that the construct that causes an error with 2 parameters works okay with 1 parameter (3 lines above). Is that a limitation? Am I missing something? It is not really a serious problem, just curious to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Z3 C++ API overloads the `operator()` for the class `func_decl`. The idea is to allow us to create small terms using a natural notation. The current available overloads are:

```
    expr operator()() const;
    expr operator()(unsigned n, expr const * args) const;
    expr operator()(expr_vector const& v) const;
    expr operator()(expr const & a) const;        expr operator()(int a) const;
    expr operator()(expr const & a1, expr const & a2) const;
    expr operator()(expr const & a1, int a2) const;
    expr operator()(int a1, expr const & a2) const;
    expr operator()(expr const & a1, expr const & a2, expr const & a3) const;
    expr operator()(expr const & a1, expr const & a2, expr const & a3, expr const & a4) const;
    expr operator()(expr const & a1, expr const & a2, expr const & a3, expr const & a4, expr const & a5) const;
```

Note that there is no overload for `operator()(int a1, int a2)`. This is why your example does not work. It is not hard to add a new overload for this case, but it gets really tedious for 3 or more arguments. The C++ API is defined on top of the C API. The file `z3++.h` is self contained. We can add the new overloads without recompiling Z3. We just need to include

```
   expr operator()(int a1, int a2) const;
```

in the class `func_decl`, and the following piece of code after the implementation of the other `func_decl::operator()` overloads.

```
 inline expr func_decl::operator()(int a1, int a2) const {
     Z3_ast args[2] = { ctx().num_val(a1, domain(0)), ctx().num_val(a1, domain(1)) };
     Z3_ast r = Z3_mk_app(ctx(), *this, 2, args);
     ctx().check_error();
     return expr(ctx(), r);
 }
```